# Tukey significance lines in box plot in R

Tags: r, plot, box, significance, tukey

I am trying to add significance lines in my boxplot using the following syntax:

```r
> my_comparisons <- list( c("Cluster 2L", "Cluster 1L"), c("Cluster 3L",
> "Cluster 1L"), c("Cluster 3L", "Cluster 2L") )
> 
> B2 <- ggboxplot(VCPedu_LOW, x = "clustergroup", y =
> "Water_cons_m3_stnd",
>           main = "C",
>           palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
>           order = c("Cluster 1L", "Cluster 2L", "Cluster 3L"),
>           ylab = "Blue water use, in m3/1000 kcal", xlab = "", 
>           ylim = c(0, 0.6)) B2 + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons) + stat_compare_means(label.y = 0.6,  method = 
> "anova")
```

This is my result: [image: Tukey-style box plots with p-values]

but my outcome of the Tukey test is as follow:

```r
> Fit: aov(formula = VCPedu_LOW$Water_cons_m3_stnd ~ clustergroup, data
> = VCPedu_LOW)

$clustergroup

                            diff          lwr        upr     p adj
Cluster 2L-Cluster 1L 0.01166782 0.0010159647 0.02231968 0.0277671
Cluster 3L-Cluster 1L 0.02468889 0.0154787818 0.03389900 0.0000000
Cluster 3L-Cluster 2L 0.01302107 0.0004250736 0.02561706 0.0408405*
```

Can someone please help me to get the right p values into my box plot including the significance lines?

Comment: can you tell us what package(s) `ggboxplot()` and `stat_compare_mean()` come from? (they're not part of base R ...)

Comment: they come from ggplot

Comment: I don't think so. Some searching suggests they're from `ggpubr` (an add-on package that extends `ggplot2`). Could you edit your question to add this information? It would be best if you could give us a [mcve] ... For example, you could use the built-in `mtcars` data set ..